# 4x4 transformation matrix between two sets of three points -- approach?

Tags: matrix, 3d

With a truedepth camera, I have measured two sets of three points in 3D space -- basically keypoints on an object that has moved over time.  I would like to calculate the 4x4 transformation matrix that matches one set to the other set (which won't be perfect, but want to get as close as possible).  The best technique I can come up with is some sort of gradient descent optimization on the terms of the matrix, minimizing the sum of squared distances between the calculated set and target.  But I *feel* like there's a better, more elegant approach out there. Does anyone have any thoughts or pointers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is to compute the best rigid transformation matching two sets of points. There is a closed form solution for that. That problem has several names: Kabsch Problem, Whaba Problem, Procrustes Problem and Attitude Estimation problem (with some well known algorithms like QUEST and FOAM)

See:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm