# Calculating a transformation matrix from corresponding points (ThreeJS)

Tags: math, matrix, three.js, 3d, transformation

I have two sets of three corresponding (x,y) points, `a` and `b`:

```
// (example values, not actual)
const a = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
const b = [/* etc, same format as `a` */]
```

I'm using ThreeJS and trying to come up with a general way to create a transformation matrix that will convert any point in `a` space to `b` space.

My thought process is:

1. Convert each set of points to a matrix:

```
const aMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3(
  a[0][0], a[0][1], 1,
  a[1][0], a[1][1], 1,
  a[2][0], a[2][1], 1,
)

const bMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3(
  b[0][0], b[0][1], 1,
  b[1][0], b[1][1], 1,
  b[2][0], b[2][1], 1,
)
```

2. If I'm right in thinking for matrix M, M(aMatrix) = bMatrix, then M = bMatrix(aMatrix<sup>-1</sup>). In Three, I would think this would translate to:

```
const M = bMatrix.clone().multiply(aMatrix.clone().invert())
```

3. Then, if I have a mesh `mesh` in `a` space, I would think I'd be able to do:

```
mesh.matrix.setFromMatrix3(M)
```

and see the mesh scaled and rotated to be in `b` space.

This doesn't seem to be working, though - the resulting model is skewed rather than rotated/scaled. I'm less familiar with matrix transformations compared to vector-based transformations so am not sure if I'm missing something or if my  process is incorrect - any thoughts on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know ThreeJS, but I think you've simply got your matrix multiplications backwards. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096873/how-to-find-rotation-and-translation-transformation-matrix-between-correspondi

Comment: You need two sets of four 3D-points.

Answer (score 0):

`Matrix3` in three.js aren't meant to convey "positions", they are `transform matrix` and `Mesh` uses `Matrix4` ([documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mesh#api/en/core/Object3D.matrix)).

[Transformation Matrix](https://www.brainvoyager.com/bv/doc/UsersGuide/CoordsAndTransforms/SpatialTransformationMatrices.html) combines :

- Translation matrix;
- Scaling matrix;
- Rotating matrix.

For your point `2)`, if you create the two meshes with the 2 sets of points and get their transformation matrices, they will contain no transformations ([`Identity Matrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)), so, the operation would give you an [`Identity Matrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) resulting in no transformation (https://codepen.io/trinketmage/pen/MWxGeqd). For that operation to make sense, you need transformation matrices to be different.

I don't want to be misleading, but to my humble knowledge, there is no way to calculate from two set of 3D coordinates a transformation matrix, with the actual API in three.js. But I believe there could be an algorithmic approach for this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69510507/3382951)).